# Serenity BDD screenplay verify multiple text elements on the webpage

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

How do I verify multiple text elements and links in the bdd using Serenity BDD ?

I am using below code but using this approach i have to write same copy of code for every element on the webpage which is timeconsuming, is there any alternate way to parametrize and verify values

```
private static final String APIBUILDER = "app-data-api-card  .card-header";

    @Subject("the displayed notebook")
    public static class APIBUILDER implements Question<String> {
        @Override

        public String answeredBy(Actor actor) {
            return BrowseTheWeb.as(actor).findBy(APIBUILDER).getText();
        }


        public static Question<String> value() { return new APIBUILDER(); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Ensure library

```
static By FIRST_NAME_FIELD = By.id("first_name");
static By LAST_NAME_FIELD = By.id("last_name");

actor.attemptsTo(
    Ensure.that(FIRST_NAME_FIELD).text().isEqualTo("Foo")
    Ensure.that(LAST_NAME_FIELD).text().isEqualTo("Bar")
);
```

If you want soft assertions, you could also do this:

```
    Ensure.enableSoftAssertions();
    actor.attemptsTo(
        Ensure.that(FIRST_NAME_FIELD).text().isEqualTo("Foo")
        Ensure.that(LAST_NAME_FIELD).text().isEqualTo("Bar")
    );
    Ensure.reportSoftAssertions();
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the example with soft assertions doesn't work as intended. When the first check fails then the next one is not executed.